# Difference between %d%d and %d %d

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

Does `scanf("%d%d");` act like `scanf("%d %d");`?

or

Does `scanf("%d %d");` act like `scanf("%d%d);`?

or

They are not the same?

I know that white space consumes any input white space in the buffer.

When I input `[32 44]` how they distinguish 32 is first `%d` and 44 is second `%d`,
if it is true?

Comment: Can you provide an example program that shows what you are talking about, with given inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Consuming whitespace is a function for `scanf` format specifiers, not `printf` format specifiers.

Comment: Oops my mistake

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `"%d%d"` and `"%d %d"` will perform identically with `scanf`.

In a `scanf` format specifier, `%d` means "skip any whitespace, then read an integer".

In a `scanf` format specifier, a space character means "skip any whitespace".

So `"%d%d"` means "skip any whitespace, then read an integer, then skip any whitespace, then read an integer".

And `"%d %d"` means "skip any whitespace, then read an integer, then skip any whitespace, then skip any whitespace, then read an integer".

Comment: Thank you! I think it is best answer.

Comment: Note that all but three [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) formats automatically and unavoidably skip leading white space, including newlines., so white space before most conversions is irrelevant (but basically harmless).  The exceptions are `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets), and `%n` — and literal strings.  There, white space before the conversion specification can be relevant.

Comment: An interesting corollary is that white space between literal strings in the format string is optional.  Given `int i1, i2; scanf("%d words separated by spaces %d", &i1, &i2);`, you can input `2 words separated by spaces 3` or `2wordsseparatedbyspaces3` and both inputs are valid.  Of course, you can use multiple spaces, newlines and tabs between the words too.